# Implementing Comparable<T> in a subclass

Tags: java

Let's suppose I have 3 classes like so:

Rule.class:

```
public class Rule {
    private String name;
    //Getters & Setters
}
```

PrioritizedRule.class:

```
public class PrioritizedRule extends Rule implements Comaparable<PrioritizedRule> {

     private int priority;

     @Override
     public int compareTo(PrioritizedRule y) {
         return Integer.compare(this.getPriority(), y.getPriority());
     }
     //Getters & Setters
}
```

SpecificRule.class

```
public class SpecificRule extends PrioritizedRule {
     private double specificValue;
     //Getters & Setters
}
```

Is it considered bad practice to implement Comparable in this subclass like that, since it's not necessarily guaranteeing that a SpecificRule compares consistent with equals? ([which is recommended according to the Java documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html))

Comment: It is even more considered bad practice to extend concrete classes :-) Form a common abstract base class without extending concrete behavior, because objects of your subclass can be treated like objects of your super class and change base class behavior so that others might be depended on implementation details of your super class which is against OO principles.

Comment: You've more or less answered your own question. A `compareTo()` that is inconsistent with `equals()` is a really bad idea. Of course in your case this is just a potential but why take the risk?

Comment: That's what I thought. So you'd rather use a special Comparator for that purpose?

Comment: You'd be violating the Liskov Substitution principle (see [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle)), which (simply explained) means that if your program works with a `Rule` reference, then it should behave the same whether it's either a `PrioritizedRule` or a `SpecificRule`. (If one is `Comparable` and the other is not, then you directly violate this principle).

Comment: @Magnamag Okay, but how do I sort the PrioritizedRule und its extending classes without bad practice?

Comment: @Magnamag I disagree with your statement. Subclasses tend to have additional functionality than the base class  or interface. To say that a sub-class should never implement an interface that the base class does not is WAY too restrictive. So long as all sub-classes meet the contract of the base class, having one meet an additional contract is not a problem. All `Rules` can be used the same way via the `Rule` contract. If you happen to know what kind of `Rule` you have, you might have access to an additional API.

Comment: Yes. Use a Comparator.

Comment: @John B Fair enough, you're right and I wasn't clear enough with the example. In this specific case, if `SpecificRule` was also `Comparable`, implemented **consistently** with `PrioritizedRule.compareTo()`, then everything should be OK.

Comment: @cbach Or, as @John B said, use a `Comparator`, i.e. see [Collections.sort()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort-java.util.List-java.util.Comparator-) method docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @John B said, use a `Comparator`, i.e. see [Collections.sort()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort-java.util.List-java.util.Comparator-) method docs.

Or you could also let `SpecificRule` implement `Comparable` in a **consistent** way with `PrioritizedRule.compareTo()` method:

```
public class SpecificRule 
    extends PrioritizedRule 
    implements Comaparable<SpecificRule> {

    private double specificValue;

    @Override
    public int compareTo(SpecificRule y) {
        int c = Integer.compare(this.getPriority(), y.getPriority());
        if (c == 0) {
            return Double.compare(this.getSpecificValue(), y.getSpecificValue());
        }
        return c;
    }

    //Getters & Setters

}
```

Answer (score -3):

This is probably not the answer you're looking for and I realise I'm a bit off topic, but I consider implementing `Comparable` itself to be bad practice.

Most (all?) methods that can work with instances of `Comparable` have a version that uses a `Comparator`. By using `Comparable`, you hard-code a single possible sort order for your class.

Say, for example, that you have a `Person` class with `firstName`, `lastName` and `age` fields. If you were to make `Person` an instance of `Comparable`, you'd need to decide which sort order to apply - on the first name? last name? the age? ascending or descending?

If, on the other hand, you were to provide a default `Comparator` implementation (as a static field, say), you'd let users of your `Person` class decide exactly what they need, depending on the context and their use case.

This makes sense, really: a `Person` does not know how to sort itself. The entity doing the sorting knows how it should be done, and odds are not all entities will agree on the same sort order.

Comment: Implementing `Comparable` is to provide *natural ordering* to your class, whether it is a good or a bad idea is context-specific, so I wouldn't make such generalizations.

Comment: IMHO, your statement that `implementing Comparable itself to be bad practice` is either false or an overstatement. I will agree with your stated case WRT classes that do not implicitly imply order (such as your Person case). But there are classes that would implicitly have a DEFAULT order (Age, Size, Area, ModelYear, etc). To say that you shouldn't implement `Comparable` in these cases seems wrong to me.

Comment: I think `Comparable` is indeed implemented far more often than it should be. And it's true that more consideration should be given to the question of whether a given ordering truly represents the natural ordering of an entity. But to consider the whole thing a bad practice is clearly wrong. It's a code smell at worst.

Comment: Agreed. Bad practice is too harsh, code smell is a much better description for this, thanks.